# when i want to return empty char i get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Tags: java, hashset

I tried to code method that gives first reccuring char 
but when the string doesn't have any I get this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
```

Code:

```
static char firstReccuring(char str[]){
    HashSet<Character> map = new HashSet<>();

    for(int i=0; i<=str.length; i++ ) {
        char ch = str[i];
        if(map.contains(ch)) {
            return ch;
        }else {
            map.add(ch);
        }
    }

    return '0';
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "abc";
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(firstReccuring(arr));

}
```

Comment: `i<=str.length` should be `i<str.length` otherwise the last index will be out of bounds, i.e. if the string has a length of 10 the valid indices range from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 1):

Turn  `i<=str.length` into  `i<str.length`
Your String only has three characters, meaning the biggest index in the array will be 2

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i<=str.length; i++ ) {`
```

remove the equal because if string have length of n , max accessible index is n-1